# How to capture a topology created in mininet

Tags: mininet, opendaylight

Hi guys iam right now working on mininet and openday light I just want to know how the topology which is generated in mininet is displayed on the DLUX ??

Answer (score 0):

At least in lithium version, after starting karaf (~/$YOUR_PROJECT/karaf/target/assembly/bin/karaf), If you try to install the next features:

```
feature:install odl-base-all odl-aaa-authn odl-restconf odl-adsal-northbound odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-l2switch-switch odl-dlux-all odl-openflowplugin-all
```

And after that, try to run Opendaylight web UI (normally located in localhost, port 8080, if you haven't change default port):

http://localhost:8080/index.html

Add with admin/admin, you must be able to see Topology and Nodes.

Cheers